# Create a graphql api in Java which streams an arrowflight stream

Tags: spring-boot, graphql-java, graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter, apache-arrow-flight

I need to create a graphql api which streams an arrowflight stream. I'm unable to find any documentation which can help me figure out a way to do this in Java. Below is the sample code I have:

```
    String query = String.format(
            "SELECT %s FROM <table> ORDER BY %s LIMIT %s OFFSET %s",
            String.join(",", fieldNames), String.join(",", orderByList), limit, offset);

    FlightStream flightStream = arrowFlightClientService.initiateQuery(query);
    while (flightStream.next()) {
      .....//need to return each stream response as a stream which can be subscribed by the client
    }
    flightStream.close();
```

Any help to point to any documentation/code would be great.